# ParseReact: Observe queries depending on other queries?

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs

This is more a question of practices than an issue (though I suppose it's an issue in that I don't know if this is possible) with the Parse-React library, but I have a special case where I need to make a query based off of info I get from another query. Ideally I want to do this in the same component. Is this possible?

e.g. the way I have my project setup right now using only Parse and React libraries (not Parse-React) is:

```
var QueryOne = new ParseQuery("QueryOne");
QueryOne.find({
  success: function(results) {
    var listOfThingsToGetFromQueryTwo = results.attributes.listOfThingsToGetFromQueryTwo;

    var QueryTwo = new ParseQuery("QueryTwo").containedIn("id", listOfThingsToGetFromQueryTwo).find({
        success: function(results) { /* do other stuff */ }
    });
  }
});
```

This works for a one-time query, but I'd like to use some of the more reactive features of Parse-React. So my question is, using Parse-React, can I make a component observe (in this example) QueryOne AND a QueryTwo depending on QueryOne?

I naively set out to implement this using by observing QueryOne in a parent component and passing that data as a prop to a child component, and observing QueryTwo from the child component, but I realize now that the `observe` function isn't triggered on prop updates so the query isn't rerun. Is there some way of triggering the query to rerun from `componentWillUpdate`?

I filed an issue directly on the parse-react github but haven't heard back. (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/124) Would greatly appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Turns out the `observe` function is passed `newProps` and `newState` as parameters, so if I make QueryOne in the parent container and pass the child the props, I can then use in the containedIn filter on the child with `newProps` and it works as expected.